# Java annotation to determine whether the annotated method executes

Tags: java, spring, annotations

In my methods, all my code is in an if block, testing certain condition.

```
public void myMethod() {
    if (/* some condition */) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

I would like to do this by annotation - meaning the annotation will execute some code that will "decide" whether or not the method should be invoked.

```
@AllowInvokeMethod(/* some parameters to decide */) 
public void myMethod() {
    //do something (if annotation allows invokation)
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Spring AOP to create an ASpect to advise methods that are annotated your custom annotation

For example create an FilteredExecution annotation to be specified on your methods

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface FilteredExecution{
   Class<? extends ExecutionFilter> value();
}
```

ExecutionFilter is an interface to decide whether execution should occur

```
public interface ExecutionFilter{

   boolean sholudExecute();

}
```

Then the aspect

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class FilteredExceutionAspect{

  @Around("@annotion(filterAnnotation)")
  public void filter(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp , FilteredExecution filterAnnotation){
     boolean shouldExecute = checkShouldExecute(filterAnnotation);
     if(shouldExecute){
        pjp.proceed();
     }
  }

  private boolean checkShouldExecute(FilteredExecution filterAnnotation){
     //use reflection to invoke the ExecutionFilter specified on filterAnnotatoon
  }
```

You need to setup your context so that your beans with the custom annotation are auto proxied by using @EnableAspectjAutoProxy on your configuration class

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, documentation above metoh.
this annotation is show when the method is invoke, and see the document of
meothd

```
    /** 
      *   descripcion of the method
      * @param value , any value 
      */
    public void myMethod(String value) {
    //do something (if annotation allows invokation)
}
```

if you put this structure you can't see the documentation when you
call some method,,

```
 //descripcion of the method
  public void myMethod(String value) {
        //do something (if annotation allows invokation)
    }
```

in my case, it works, i hope this works for you

Comment: "this annotation is show when the method is invoke, and see the document of meothd" Not really. You can generate html-pages based on javadoc-comments, but they are not "shown" when the "method is invoked". Do you mean by any chance the tool tip of your IDE? Your answer does not tackle OP's question.